# Relação cor de fundo de um app x eficiência energética

Tags: android, ios, mobile

Pensando em uma aplicação mobile, qual a melhor paleta de cores em relação ao consumo energético?

Por exemplo, digamos que eu esteja desenvolvendo um app e queira focar no consumo de bateria do mesmo. Imaginando um ambiente ideal em que a luminosidade e consumo de dados móveis não afetem o tempo da carga, qual a cor mais indicada para o fundo desse suposto aplicativo? Qual é a cor mais eficiente, um fundo preto ou tons mais escuros ou um fundo branco ou tons mais claros?

Em outras palavras (e falando de maneira bem tosca): é consumida mais energia para gerar uma tela totalmente preta ou uma tela totalmente branca? Há essa diferenciação?

Na questão descarto qualquer tipo de UX, questiono apenas nas questões de eficiência e consumo puro.

Comment: Cara, assim, eu acho que uma paleta de cores não afeta em nada na bateria do dispositivo... Isso é uma questão de UX.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Depende da tecnologia da tela.

Telas com iluminação de fundo gastam mais no preto, telas com led nos "pixels" gastam mais no branco, mas ambos são irrelevantes perto de outros fatores.

Veja esta imagem, divulgada por um conhecido fabricante:

[image: Representação das duas tecnologias em imagem]

Para você entender melhor:

Um LCD convencional tem um fundo branco, sempre iluminado. O LCD em si é transparente e os *pixels* "tampam" a luz branca quando são energizados. No LCD, a energia "tampa" a luz.

Uma tela OLED, por sua vez, é preta, e cada *pixel* é um LED independente. Eles acendem quando a energia passa por eles. No OLED, a energia vira luz.

### Relevância:

Na prática, a diferença não justifica a preocupação do ponto de vista de design.

Primeiro, pelo fato de que você não tem controle sobre isto como programador. Não há uma maneira confiável de se identificar isto, e a diferença prática é irrisória no dia a dia.

Um simples loop mal feito é mais problemático que a cor da tela. Melhor aprender a lidar com os *idle states* do processador, economizar recursos de processamento e de conectividade, coisa que todo bom manual de desenvolvedor costuma abranger.

A cor da tela, por outro lado, tem que facilitar a vida do usuário para ele ficar menos tempo procurando o que quer. De nada adianta economizar uma quantidade desprezível de energia se o usuário ficar mais tempo usando a aplicação.

<sup><sub>Isso me lembra aquelas campanhas do "pixel preto", que causavam mais dano do que solução, com o advento dos monitores LCD com backlight.</sub></sup>